# R: How to create multiple matrices of splited data?

Tags: r

I am using trade data (FAO) which I would like to turn into matrices (per Item and Year). Therefore I've done a split:

```
# import is the original df
import_YI <- split(import, list(import$Item, import$Year))
import_YI_lap <- lapply(seq_along(import_YI), function(x) as.data.frame(import_YI[[x]])[, 1:11])
```

and the data looks like this (you can find test data at the end) :

```
[[1]]
RC         PC       Item       Year    Value   
Argentina  Chile    Almonds    1996    1108  
Algeria    Spain    Almonds    1996    1  
....
[[2]]
....
[[3]]
....
[[n]]
```

I used the `cast` function (below) to create a matrix for almonds in 2012:

```
# import_almonds2012 is a test subset from import df (with import values for almonds in 2012)
RCPC <- cast(RC ~ PC, data =import_almonds2012, value = "Value")
```

**Now my question:** how can I do matrices of all Items/Years (~100 Items and 17 years!!) from the `import_YI_lap` df? My problem is that I don't know (1) how to operate the levels/ojects in this df (`[[1]], [[2]]...`). Or there a better way to split data or to save the splited df into objects? And (2) how to create all the needed matrices without coping thousend lines of code. **Loops? If yes, how??**

**here a test-dataset:**

```
import<- data.frame(RC=c("DE", "IT", "USA"),
                PC = c("BRA", "ARG"),
                Item = c("Almonds", "Apples"),
                Year = c(1996,1997,1998),
                Value = c(1,5,3,2,8,3))

import_YI <- split(import, list(import$Item, import$Year))
import_YI_lap <- lapply(seq_along(import_YI), function(x) as.data.frame(import_YI[[x]])[, 1:5])
import_YI_lap
```

Comment: Please show a reproducible example and expected result based on that example.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to test without data, but you can try this:

```
do.call(rbind,import_YI_lap)
```